# Два SPI мастера для одного slave

Tags: arduino, spi, электроника

Есть внешний контроллер, к которому у меня нет доступа. Он общается с 3-wire EEPROM AT93C56B по SPI. Нужно перехватывать момент записи и считывать записанные данные. Насколько я понимаю, SPI не позволяет организовать подключение вида два masters и один slave.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно обойти этот момент. В электротехнике полный профан, но пришлось походу дела разобраться.

Comment: Ну если ваш контроллер висит на SPI вы можете организовать прослушивание шины и получение всех данных, которые по ней передаются.

Comment: Т.е. садиться на пины выхода МК, который обращается к EEPROM, становиться для него slave и самому дублировать запросы к памяти? Или можно как-то проще?

Comment: Зачем Slave? Слушать что он делает, разбирать протокол и тем самым получать данные.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а как подключаться? Просто воткнуться в те же пины, только поменять местами MOSI и MISO?

Comment: Нет, вам по сути надо оба провода типа MISO, если вы хотите и ответы слышать. То есть надо по сути два контроллера, которые слушают.